# MySQL selecting the last queries with given id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with data from different devices. Each device have an id. An insert statement is executed every time the state of the device is changed.

I want to select the last entries from all of the devices.

I am using this code:

```
SELECT device_id, entry_id, data, entry_date
            FROM some_table
            group by device_id
            order by device_id asc, entry_date desc;
```

but it returns me the first entries for each device, not the last.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.device_id, t1.entry_id, t1.data, t1.entry_date
            FROM some_table as t1 inner join
(
select device_id,max(entry_date) as entry_date from some_table
group by device_id
) as t2 on t1.device_id=t2.device_id and t1.entry_date=t2.entry_date
```

Comment: I receive an error message: 'Error Code: 1052. Column 'device_id' in field list is ambiguous'

Comment: Are you sure? You won't get that error Did you change anything?

Comment: I only added more columns in the first select statement. This shouldn't  have any influence.

Comment: Then you need to qualify the alias name like t1.new_column, etc

Comment: Yes, I've missed one. Thank you very much! :)))

Answer (score 0):

the ordering is depending on sequence of each order by field. So if you want to get ordering first by date, change the sequence of ordering:

```
SELECT device_id, entry_id, data, entry_date
            FROM some_table
            group by device_id
            order by  entry_date desc,device_id asc
```

Comment: This doesn't help. When using order by, the query has already grouped the entries... taking the firs ones, not the last ones..